# JQueryUI DatePicker in Nested ascx controls; sub-ascx datepicker does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jquery .datepicker in an ascx control and a second one in a ascx inside the first ascx. The one in the sub-control doesn't work.

When I hover over the image in the first control, it's giving the path for the image in the subcontrol rather than the first control.

How do I fix this? I've searched endless questions on stackoverflow and others and haven't found anything similar.  These datepickers are in two separate controls on the same page.

Here's the code:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

' type="text/javascript">

' type="text/javascript">

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $('#' + '<%= txtDateofBirth.ClientID %>').datepicker({
             changeMonth: true,
             changeYear: true,
             yearRange: '1910:' + new Date(1910, 1 - 1, 1).getYear,
             minDate: new Date(1910, 1 - 1, 1),
             maxDate: new Date(new Date(1910, 1 - 1, 1).getYear, 1 - 1, 1)
         });
     });
     $.datepicker.setDefaults({
         showOn: "both",
         buttonImageOnly: true,
         buttonImage: '<%=ResolveUrl("Images/Icons/Classy24/calendar_date.png") %>'
     });
```

```
<input type="text" id="txtDateofBirth" name="txtDateofBirth" runat="server" width="100"/>
```

SECOND CONTROL INSIDE THE FIRST CONTROL:
(this is inside a folder names Controls off the first control's folder

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

' type="text/javascript">

' type="text/javascript">

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $('#' + '<%= txtDepDateofBirth.ClientID %>').datepicker({
             changeMonth: true,
             changeYear: true,
             yearRange: '1910:' + new Date(1910, 1 - 1, 1).getYear,
             minDate: new Date(1910, 1 - 1, 1),
             maxDate: new Date(new Date(1910, 1 - 1, 1).getYear, 1 - 1, 1)
         });
     });
     $.datepicker.setDefaults({
         showOn: "both",
         buttonImageOnly: true,
         buttonImage: '<%=ResolveUrl("Images/Icons/Classy24/calendar_date.png") %>'
     });
```

```
<input type="text" id="txtDepDateofBirth" name="txtDepDateofBirth" runat="server" width="100"/>
```

NOTE: the button image in both cases is coded as:
    buttonImage: '<%=ResolveUrl("Images/Icons/Classy24/calendar_date.png") %>'

And I have the image in two places:

maincontrol.ascx/images/icons/etc.

maincontrol folder/controls/images/icons etc.

When I hover over the main control's image I get the controls/images location instead of the maincontrol.ascx/images etc. location.

THANK YOU! I'll mark the correct answer as the answer of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my code above so that it is correct; after studying it more I saw that this line which is now correct:

```
$('#' + '<%= txtDepDateofBirth.ClientID %>').datepicker({
```

was incorrectly written as:

```
$('#' + 'txtDepDateofBirth.ClientID %>').datepicker({
```

leaving off the:

```
<%=
```

I hope this example helps someone trying to do the same thing